# Spread data with non-unique keys with R

Tags: r

I have the following data frame:

| ID | Group |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | A |
| 1 | B |
| 2 | C |
| 2 | D |

And I want to reshape the data frame into a wider version in terms of ID. Thus, the new data frame looks like this:

| ID | Group1 | Group2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | A | B |
| 2 | C | D |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by adding a helper column and then using `tidyr::pivot_wider()`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

data <- tibble(
  id = c(1, 1, 2, 2),
  group = letters[1:4]
)

# Add a helper column to use when pivoting. This uses the row number
# over each subgroup, i.e. over each value of `id`
transformed_data <- data %>% 
  group_by(id) %>% 
  mutate(helper = paste0("Group", row_number())) %>% 
  ungroup()

# Here's what the helper column looks like
transformed_data
#> # A tibble: 4 x 3
#>      id group helper
#>   <dbl> <chr> <chr> 
#> 1     1 a     Group1
#> 2     1 b     Group2
#> 3     2 c     Group1
#> 4     2 d     Group2

# Pivot the data using the helper column
transformed_data %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = helper, values_from = group)
#> # A tibble: 2 x 3
#>      id Group1 Group2
#>   <dbl> <chr>  <chr> 
#> 1     1 a      b     
#> 2     2 c      d
```